# Postgres Partitioning Query Performance when Partitioned for Delete

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

We are on Postgresql 12 and looking to partition a group of tables that are all related by Data Source Name.  A source can have tens of millions of records and the whole dataset makes up about 900GB of space across the 2000 data sources. We don't have a good way to update these records so we are looking at a full dump and reload any time we need to update data for a source. This is why we are looking at using partitioning so we can load the new data into a new partition, detach (and later drop) the partition that currently houses the data, and then attach the new partition with the latest data.  Queries will be performed via a single ID field.  My concern is that since we are partitioning by source name and querying by an ID that isn't used in the partition definition that we won't be able to utilize any partition pruning and our queries will suffer for it.

How concerned should we be with query performance for this use case?  There will be an index defined on the ID that is being queried, but based on the Postgres documentation it can add a lot of planning time and use a lot of memory to service queries that look at many partitions.

Comment: If your queries do not include the partition key, then yes, the read performance will be worse than before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance will suffer, but it will depend on the number of partitions how much. The more partitions you have, the slower both planning and execution time will get, so keep the number low.

You can save on query planning time by defining a prepared statement and reusing it.